# A footer in different languages

Tags: php

I have a web in different languages. I make an include for the footer. The easiest way could be to have a different footer for each language. But is it possible to have just one footer and change the few sentences that are different in each language?

In all pages put the same include:

```
<?php include('footer.php'); ?>
```

Then, in the includes just change what is different. Something like:

```
<footer> 

    <?php echo $text; ?> <br><br>

</footer>
</body>
</html>

<?php 
if ('<html lang="en">')
    $text = 'Some text in English';
elseif ('<html lang="fr">')
    $text = 'Français';
?>
```

(In each page I have the html lang= )

What is the better way to have a footer in different languages?

(I am just learning php, so please, just help me with the basics, where to begin)

Comment: PHP is not Javascript, just declare a variable on the top and compare using equality operator on footer

Comment: Why the negative point? what should I do better?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay so first you need to create translation files for all languages you wish to support. Store them in "/lang/en.php" and "/lang/fr.php".

"lang/en.php"

```
<?php
    return [
        "title" => "My site",
        "welcome" => "Welcome",
        "goodbye" => "Goodbye"
    ]
?>
```

"lang/fr.php"

```
<?php
    return [
        "title" => "Mon site",
        "welcome" => "Bienvenue",
        "goodbye" => "Au revoir"
    ]
?>
```

Next, you include the appropriate language file in your php page:

"index.php"

```
<?php
    $locale = $_SESSION['locale']; // this is "en" or "fr", depending on a choice the user made earlier
    $lang = require("/lang/$locale.php"); // load "/lang/en.php" or "/lang/fr.php"
    $user = $_SESSION['username']; // e.g. "Bart"
?>
<html>
    <head>
        <title><?php echo $lang['title']; ?></title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <?php include('header.php'); ?>
        <main>content</main>
        <?php include('footer.php'); ?>
    </body>
</html>
```

And in your header/footer you can just use $lang as well:

"header.php"

```
<header>
    <p><?php echo $lang['welcome'] . ', ' . $user; ?></p>
</header>
```

It's important to know that you should include your language file only in pages that a user will view directly (i.e. don't include it in partial views like header.php)

Comment: I do not understand what you put in the lang/fr.php and land/en.php, why just return [] , what is this, a function, an array? is not there anything missing?

Comment: @Nrc It's an associative array, it maps labels like "goodbye" to "Au revoir". Then you can simply use that label (i.e. `$lang['goodbye']`) and it will be replaced by the mapped string (i.e. `Au revoir`)

Comment: Ok, now I understand. Wouldn't be easier to put in the external file $lang = array (each array) and call that when you need it: require "lang/fr.php"; Sorry if it is too basic, I am just learning. (I have been searching for php return an array and I cannot find it and the code editor gives me an error in the return point

Answer (score 1):

You can create a poor man's translation function:

```
function translate($sentence, array $vars = null, $lang = 'en') {
    static $table = array();
    if ( ! isset($table[$lang])) {
        $table[$lang] = require(ROOT."/lang/{$lang}.php");
    }
    $trans = isset($table[$lang][$sentence]) ? $table[$lang][$sentence] : $sentence;
    if ( ! empty($vars)) {
        $trans = strtr($trans, $vars);
    }
    return $trans;
}
```

You can then create some language files, such as:

```
<?php
// ROOT/lang/de.php
return [
    'Welcome :name' => 'Willkommen :name',
    'Thank you'     => 'Danke',
];
```

And then in your scripts you can translate stuff:

```
<header>
    <?php echo translate('Welcome :name', [':name' => 'Bob'], 'de') ?>
</header>
```

---

Instead of using a function you could also just include the language file and then use that.

```
<?php
// some-page.php
$lang = require(ROOT."/lang/{$_SESSION['user.lang']}.php");
$name = $_SESSION['user.name'];
?>
<header>
    <?php echo str_replace(':name', $name, $lang['Welcome :name']) ?>
</header>
```

It will require you to do some more work, but if you find it to be more to your liking then okay.

Comment: Why not simply `$lang = require("lang/en.php"); echo $lang["greeting"];`?

Comment: @Bart Because that would load the language file every time the function is used. It is better to stick it into memory (using the [`static` variable `$table`](http://php.net//manual/en/language.variables.scope.php#language.variables.scope.static)) than loading the file multiple times.

Comment: No, but I mean *instead* of having a function at all, just put the first statement on the top of your "root" PHP file (only once) and then simply use `$lang` in all your files as if it were a global variable?

Comment: @Bart you may wanna post this comment as an answer providing a small example, this approach is better than all the rest.

Comment: @Bart can you explain more please? For me all the answers are too complicated. I am just learning php and I cannot understand. Your solution seem more simple and clear. Can you explain it for a beginner like me, please?

Answer (score 0):

You could set a session that contains the language such as:

```
<?php
    session_start();
    $_SESSION['language'] = "EN";
?>
```

Then in the footer:

```
<?php
    switch($_SESSION['language']) {
        case 'EN':
            $sentences['site_slogan'] = "This is your site slogan";
            $sentences['site_messag'] = "This is your site message";
        break;
        case 'FA':
            $sentences['site_slogan'] = "This is your site slogan in FA";
            $sentences['site_messag'] = "This is your site message in FA";
        break;
    }
    echo $sentences['site_slogan'];
    echo $sentences['site_messag'];
```

Comment: I do not understand. Why do you use $sentences['site_slogan'] ? Why not just $site_slogan = "content of the var" ?